# reading back time correctly in C# which was stored by MFC earlier

Tags: c#, .net, mfc, timezone, timezone-offset

```
void CMFCVersionApp::writeTo()
{
    CTime m_runEndTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetTime();
    CTimeSpan nTimeZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset();
    unsigned long valueToPushToDataBase = (unsigned long)(m_runEndTime + nTimeZoneOffset).GetTime();
    szBuffer.Format("%ld",valueToPushToDataBase);
    if ( myFile.Open( _T("c:\\test\\myfile.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite) )
    {
        LPCTSTR p = szBuffer.GetBuffer(1024);
        myFile.Flush();
        myFile.Write(p, szBuffer.GetLength());
        myFile.Close();
    }
}

CTimeSpan CMFCVersionApp::getTimeZoneOffset()
{
   CTime currentTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetTime();
   tm t1, t2; 
   t1 = *(currentTime.GetLocalTm(&t1));
   t2 = *(currentTime.GetGmtTm(&t2));
   CTime time1(1900+t1.tm_year, t1.tm_mon+1, t1.tm_mday, t1.tm_hour, t1.tm_min,0,0);
   CTime time2(1900+t2.tm_year, t2.tm_mon+1, t2.tm_mday, t2.tm_hour, t2.tm_min,0,0);

   CTimeSpan nTimeZoneOffset = time1 - time2;
   return nTimeZoneOffset;
}

void CMFCVersionApp::readFrom()
{
   AfxMessageBox(_T("Reading.. You may attach now"));
   unsigned long valueFromDB;



   if ( myFile.Open( _T("c:\\test\\myfile.dat"), CFile::modeRead ) )
    {
        //myFile.Flush();
        myFile.Seek( 0, CFile::begin );
        myFile.Read( ArrszBuffer, sizeof( ArrszBuffer ) ); 
        valueFromDB = atoi(ArrszBuffer);
        myFile.Close();
   }

   CTime       m_ReceiverSideEndDate = valueFromDB;     
   m_ReceiverSideEndDate-= getTimeZoneOffset(); 
   CString strValue = m_ReceiverSideEndDate.Format("%c");
   AfxMessageBox(_T(strValue));
}
```

The above code is how I am writing to database and reading back from database
in MFC environment everything is fine.

The problem is, the program is running on a **US** machine, and the date of running is `15-05-2013 08:11:23` (day light time zone). So it saved that date as 1368601883 in a text file.

However when i am trying to read the same `1368601883` value with C# Code I expect to receive `15-05-2013 08:11:23`, however I am getting `15-05-2013 07:11:23`. 1 hour difference.

How can I handle this situation in C#.

Comment: Can you post the code for reading in C#? I suspect its a timezone issue..

Comment: public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(long ticks)
        {
            TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
            return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Add(span);
        }

Comment: hey,i got it.. i made a mistake. i rewritten my C# code like this.
      

public static DateTime ConvertToLocalDateTime(long ticks)
      {
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
         DateTime startTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Add(span);
         return TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(startTime).AddSeconds((DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.Now)).TotalSeconds);
      }

Comment: Why on earth are you using MFC types in your C# code??

Comment: Also, that block you posted in comments is *really* convoluted.  If you are wanting to convert a unix timestamp to a local `DateTime`, then just do this:  `DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(timestampInSeconds).ToLocalTime();`